# How to keep Divs from overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want container 2 to always be located below container 1 but outside of the "background" div.  I can do this with a wide screen but when the screen narrows. container2 floats on top of container1. How do I keep container2 below?

css container1 and container2 both have the css values from twitter's bootstrap "container" class.  I just added the 1 and 2 to help explain what I needed.

```
<div class="Background">
   <div class="container1">
      <div class="row ">
         <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row ">
         <div>
         </div>
      </div>      
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Background{
 height: 250px;
 color: #cccccc;
 }
.container {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 }
```

Comment: They both have to have `display:block`

Comment: @JoshC divs have `display:block` by default.

Comment: is `container's` `position:relative`?

Comment: @Coop Yea, but they may be set to `inline` or `inline-block` in the unknown CSS.

Comment: The HTML is working as you want, it must be something else in your CSS, floats or absolute positioning. See fiddle for it workin http://jsfiddle.net/pZQPc/1/

Comment: @JoshC Don't see the point on speculating what some code might be that we can't see. If you were going to speculate, it's less likely that the default state would have been reversed, and more likely that a float or different positioning would have been used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different layout on different screens you should use a media query:

You could use absolute positioning on a smaller screen to pull the second container over the first. You should surround them both in a div with position:relative applied

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it can affect other elements in markup but you can try :

```
.Background,.container2{
    display :block // or inline-block with clearing floats
}
```

Also consider that `.container` is suggested the outer-most element in bootstrap grid so you can either set background to absolute (to take it out of the flow) or put it inside container1.